# Python threading with discord RPC

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, discord

Porblem:it doesnt run thread_3
What is thread_3? its a discord rpc(connects to your discord aplication for example: you can set a game activity with it)
I don't know why its not working.
I am new in multithreading/threading.
Maybe someone can help me, thanks!

```
import _thread as thread
import time
from pypresence import Presence

cid = int(785560652756418621)
rpc = Presence(cid)

# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count == count:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print ("%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) ))

def print_test( threadName, delay):
    count = 0
    while count == count:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print ("%s: %s" % ( threadName, delay))
      
def thread_3(delay):
        count = 0
        while count == count:
            time.sleep(delay)
            count += 1
            # Connect to Discord
            rpc.connect()
            
            rpc.update(small_image = '512', large_image = '512',state = "Test",details = "Test", small_text="Test", large_text="Test")
            print('RPC set successfully.')
            # Update RPC every 15 seconds
            while True:
                time.sleep(10)
  
# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2) )
#    thread.start_new_thread( print_test, ("Thread-2", 4) )
   thread.start_new_thread( thread_3, ("Discord-3", 3) )
except:
   print ("Error: unable to start thread")

while 1:
   pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnt run thread_3"? What part of thread_3 is not executed?

Comment: `while True: time.sleep(10)` will run forever. The outer while loop will not be executed more than once.

Comment: Exception ignored in thread started by: <function thread_3 at 0x03694148>
TypeError: thread_3() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

@Shiva

Comment: You have defined `thread_3` function with only parameter - `delay` but you are passing two arguments. Change `def thread_3(delay)` to `def thread_3(threadName, delay)`.

Comment: Then ill get this error again

self.update_event_loop(self.get_event_loop())
  File "C:\Users\glasmor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pypresence\baseclient.py", line 80, in get_event_loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\glasmor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'

Comment: this is the error which u get if u execute the abve code

Comment: There are several issues with your code. It seems you are not well versed with Python(or programming in general).

Comment: its not my first python project i got like 100 others but its my first time with threads and multithreads i never worked with that before bcs i never needed it

Comment: anyways thanks for the help

Comment: I see lots of issue in non-threading/multiprocessing code actually.
Anyways, I would suggest you to go through - https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python to get a good understanding of multi-threading. You can skip multiprocessing and asyncio from that tutorial for now.